# Unable to debug css on soft keyboard pop up

Tags: html, css, cordova, onsen-ui, crosswalk

I am working on a Hybrid app based on `Onsen` UI.

My UI gets ruined when I open the soft keyboard on a phone and I am unable to debug my `CSS` in Chrome using inspect element, as I am not able to emulate the soft keyboard opening.

Is there any way to see `CSS` after soft keyboard pop up in inspect element?

Answer (score 0):

You must inspect your app on a physical device.

Connect your device with USB cable and use "inspect device" of your desktop Chrome.

You are able to inspect the page loaded on Chrome on mobile device ad test the behaviour of your page with soft keybord open.

Comment: Not able to do so in crosswalk ... dont knw why

Comment: I don't know crosswalk. I used it with success with html app build with cordova. You could try at first to inspect with chrome devices inspector a simple page open on mobile chrome browser. So you could understand if is a crosswalk issue or simple chrome hasn't right permission

Comment: Follow this guide https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/android_remote_debugging.html